# Tags: network-flow, max-flow

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed we have tags for both [network-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-flow) and [max-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-flow).  Does that make sense?  Is there any distinction?

There seem to be only 2 questions tagged with [max-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-flow).  Should we make [max-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-flow) a synonym of [nework-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nework-flow)?

Comment: I guess max-flow is slightly more specific; I'd tag modelling questions with [tag:network-flow] but not necessarily [tag:max-flow], which I'd reserve for max-flow algorithms and such.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in my opinion [max-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-flow) should be a synonym of [network-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-flow).

There's really no difference between them, as they are currently being used:

- We currently have only 4 questions tagged [max-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-flow).  3 out of 4 of those are also tagged [network-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-flow).
- Meanwhile, almost all questions tagged [network-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-flow) are actually about finding a maximum flow.

While in principle it would be possible to create a meaningful distinction between them, (a) it'd be a very fine line, (b) no such distinction currently exists, (c) people aren't actually using the tag that way, (d) we don't have any tag wikis or anything to guide posters to use the tags that way and most posters probably don't read tag wikis anyway, so posters will continue to use tags in a way that does not respect those fine distinctions, (e) the two are so close that I don't see much value in drawing that particular distinction anyway.

Comment: To be clear, you are proposing [tag:network-flow] <-- [tag:max-flow]?

Comment: @Raphael, yes (so network-flow would be the remaining tag that shows up; if a user types max-flow, it gets converted to network-flow).  That's based on the fact that we currently have 72 questions tagged network-flow, and only 4 tagged max-flow.   Does that seem reasonable to you?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I would vote to keep [max-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-flow).  Max-flow should apply to a strict subset of [network-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-flow) questions.  We also have [shortest-path](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortest-path), which is another class of network-flow algorithms.  It has 151 uses, which is more than double what we have on [network-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-flow).

[Shortest path problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) can be viewed as specializations of the [minimum cost flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) with costs but no capacity constraints on the links.  Similarly [Max-flow problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) can be viewed as specializations of the minimum cost flow problem with capacity constraints but zero costs on all the links.

Similarly the min-cost flow problem is itself a specialization of the linear programming problem, and multi-commodity flow problems can be formulated as integer programming problems, but I don't think we want to get rid of the [network-flow](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-flow) tag just because we already have an [integer-programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-programming) tag.

Comment: Not that I have any particular objection to this proposal, but... are there any (existing) [tag:network-flow] questions that [tag:max-flow] wouldn't apply to?

Comment: Whoa!  Not many.  Here's a few: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6773/finding-negative-cycles-for-cycle-canceling-algorithm, http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7610/xor-like-behavior-in-flow-networks, http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2283/why-is-the-complexity-of-negative-cycle-cancelling-ov%C2%B2auw

Comment: Or this one http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37237/linear-programming-formulation-of-cheapest-k-edge-path-between-two-nodes

Comment: I think we could merge [tag:max-flow] and [tag:network-flow] without merging any of those other tags.  I don't see that shortest paths or linear programming or integer programming really enter into it; there wouldn't be any inconsistency or problem created if we merged only [tag:max-flow] and [tag:network-flow] without merging it into any of those other tags.  I don't view those other tags as analogous; the situation with them is different, as they are much more recognizably distinct from network flow.

Comment: I now agree.  In practice [tag:shortest-path] is used without [tag:network-flow], while [tag:network-flow] is almost always used for max-flow/min-cut problems instead of [tag:max-flow].  It doesn't matter whether my taxonomy is technically correct or not, that's not how users are actually using the tags.

Comment: I agree as well. The fact that any P problem can be expressed as network flow problem or LP or ... does not mean we should all tag them [tag:network-flow] or [tag:linear-programming].

Comment: @Raphael, that was not my original argument.  My argument was that shortest-path _is the subclass_ of network flow problems with edge costs but infinite capacities, while max-flow _is the subclass_ of network flow problems with edge capacities, but 0 edge costs.  Further, these are the _only_ two obvious subclasses of network flow.  The argument is not "x can be expressed as y".  _Nonetheless_, since users aren't using the terms the way I use them, we should go with the wisdom of the crowd.